# How to obtain particular value from Map in a "String" format

Tags: java, android

I have a Map :

```
Map<String, String> value
```

How to obtain particular value "String" ----> "type" from json value, how do i obtain it?

I tried below code, which only returns me KEY and not VALUE

```
Iterator it = payload.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            String key = pair.getKey().toString();
            String value = pair.getValue().toString();
            Log.d("getActionValue", "key : " + key);
            Log.d("getActionValue", "value : + value");
        }
```

Comment: `Log.d("getActionValue", "value : + value");` needs to be `Log.d("getActionValue", "value :" + value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want that particular "String" ----> "type" from value, how do i
>   obtain it?

`payload` Map contains `JSONObject's` as value of every key. so to get `type` need to first convert String to `JSONObject` then get value using  `type` key:

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(value);
String strType="";
if(jsonObject.has("notification-action")){
   JSONObject jsonObjectnotification=jsonObject.optJSONObject
                                         (""notification-action"");
   if(jsonObjectnotification.has("type")){
      strType=jsonObjectnotification.optString("type");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @prosperK, I tried but it won't come inside "if" loop, that means logic to identify "type" doesn't work. Any other logic? Would "contains" work?

Comment: @user45678: But http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String) method is available which tell you JSONObject contains `type` key or not

Comment: @prosperK - This worked for me "try {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(value);
            jsonObject=jsonObject.getJSONObject("notification-action");
            String typetwo = jsonObject.getString("type");
            Toast.makeText(context,"" + typetwo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("getActionValue", "String Type Two :" + typetwo);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Do something with the exception
        }

Answer (score 4):

You don't access your variable in your output, since `value` is still in in the string. 
Change like this:

```
Log.d("getActionValue", "value : " + value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here  `Log.d("getActionValue", "value : + value");` it should be `Log.d("getActionValue", "value : "+ value);`

Try this for loop :-

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : payload.entrySet())
{
    Log.d("getActionValue", "key : " + entry.getKey());
    Log.d("getActionValue", "value :" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You logging it wrong.

Should be:

```
Log.d("getActionValue", "value : " + value);
```